# How can I store characters in flash memory STM32F4 HAL with C++?

Tags: c++, flash-memory, hal

So I have a buffer:

```
uint32_t buff[2];
buff[0] = 12;
buff[1] = 13;
...
```

I can write this to the flash memory with the method:

```
HAL_FLASH_Program(TYPEPROGRAM_WORD, (uint32_t)(startAddress+(i*4)), *buff)
```

The definition of `HAL_FLASH_Program` is:

```
HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_FLASH_Program(uint32_t TypeProgram, uint32_t Address, uint64_t Data)
```

That works perfectly. Now is there a way I can store chars instead or ints?

Comment: See [Allocating memory in Flash for user data (STM32F4 HAL)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28505272/1398841)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HAL_FLASH_Program` with `TYPEPROGRAM_BYTE` to write a single 1-byte char.

If your data is a bit long (a struct, a string...), you can also write the bulk with `TYPEPROGRAM_WORD`, or even `TYPEPROGRAM_DOUBLEWORD` (8 bytes at a time), and then either complete with single bytes as needed or pad the excess with zeros. That would certainly be a bit faster, but maybe it's not significant for you.

Comment: My data is just `TCHAR id[11]` it then contains something like `['a','B','c','D', ...]`. Could I just do `HAL_FLASH_Program(TYPEPROGRAM_BYTE, (uint32_t)(startAddress+(i*4)), *id[i]);` ?

Comment: @matt Yes, if you do that in a loop. Except that it would be `startAddress+i` (or `startAddress+i*sizeof(TCHAR)`) and `id[i]`. You also have to make sure `TCHAR` is 1 byte. `char` is always 1 byte, but `TCHAR` could be more.

Comment: @matt Also, if you want to store many things, you can use a struct with everything you want inside as a mapping, then store and load using `startAddress+offsetof(map,id[0])`.